# Strange guess for a particular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is $x'' + w^2 x = \cos w \, t$, where $x$ is a function of $t$.

For my particular solution I guessed $x_p = A \cos w \, t + B \sin w \, t$.

Then $x_p' = - w A \sin w \, t + w B \cos w \, t$ and $x_p'' = - w^2 A \cos w \, t - w^2 B \sin w \, t$.

But then $ - w^2 A \cos w \, t - w^2 B \sin w \, t + w^2 (A \cos w \, t + B \sin w \, t) = 0 \neq \cos w \, t$.

So no particular solution.

Later I found out that I was supposed to guess $x_p = A t \sin w \, t$, which I have verified does work.

So how was I supposed to know to guess that?

Of the guess lists I've seen they only list $A \cos t + B \sin t$ as guesses. None have an extra $t$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your first guess happens to be a solution to the homogeneous equation. Whenever this happens, the standard strategy is to multiply your guess by $t$. This applies to all standard guesses on your list.

Answer (score 0):

make the ansatz $$x_p=At\sin(tw)+B\cos(tw)$$